# Can PyCharm query results have a map hyperlink for geometry fields like pgAdmin?

Tags: plugins, pycharm, geospatial

In pgAdmin, if a query result has geometry field then a map icon exists so you can view the geometry on a map (leaflet):

[image]

which jumps to a geometry viewer:

[image]

Unfortunately PyCharm doesn't have this which is about the only thing holding us up from using PyCharm as our default data interfacing tool:

[image]

Is there a possibility of adding this to PyCharm or a plugin for this?

Comment: This... is really cool, I had no idea pgAdmin could do this... I guess I need to finally upgrade from 3.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't develop like this and I haven't used it personally, but it seems there is a new feature for this, shown [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tables-view-data.html#updating_table_view)

`View | Tool Windows | database` -> `Gear/Menus -> Show Geo Viewer` (Will only work if JCEF is enabled, restart required)

Since this seems like a new feature, there may be some robustness issues at this time (e.g a ticket for supporting projections other than 4326, shown [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-11128)). So your mileage may vary, but this may be something that's improved over time. If you have a team with paid licenses, I'd suggest you vote on issues you'd like to see implemented.

FWIW I'll also not you have 'PyCharm' as a tag, but this seems to be a question more related to their `DataGrip` IDE, which PyCharm is clearly using capabilities of. Your searches for help on google, etc. might be benefitted by including 'DataGrip' instead of 'PyCharm'

Comment: wow did not know about DataGrip. Thanks!